# How to output correct database row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

My code is this :

```
public function procAllianceAttRanking($limit="") {
  $q = "SELECT " . TB_PREFIX . "users.id userid, " . TB_PREFIX . "users.username username, " . TB_PREFIX . "users.alliance allyid, (

  SELECT SUM( " . TB_PREFIX . "vdata.pop ) 
  FROM " . TB_PREFIX . "vdata
  WHERE " . TB_PREFIX . "vdata.owner = userid
  )totalpop, (

  SELECT SUM( " . TB_PREFIX . "alidata.Aap ) 
  FROM " . TB_PREFIX . "alidata
  WHERE " . TB_PREFIX . "alidata.id = allyid
  )totalpoint, (

  SELECT COUNT( " . TB_PREFIX . "users.alliance ) 
  FROM " . TB_PREFIX . "users
  WHERE " . TB_PREFIX . "users.alliance = allyid
  )totalusers

  FROM " . TB_PREFIX . "users
  WHERE " . TB_PREFIX . "users.alliance > 0
  ORDER BY totalpoint DESC, allyid ASC $limit";
  return mysql_query($q);
}
```

and output code is this :

```
$sql = $ranking->procAllianceRanking();
$query = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if($query >= 1){ 
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    if($row['allyid'] == $session->alliance) {
      echo "<tr class=\"hl\"><td class=\"ra fc\" >".$rank.".</td>";
    }else {
      echo "<tr class=\"hover\"><td class=\"ra \" >".$rank.".</td>";
    }
    echo "<td class=\"al \" ><a href=\"allianz.php?aid=".$row['allyid']."\">".$database->getAllianceName($row['allyid'])."</a></td>";

    echo "<td class=\"pla \" >".$row['totalusers']."</td>";
        echo "<td class=\"av \">".round($row['totalpop']/$row['totalusers'])."</td>";
      echo "<td class=\"po lc\">".$row['totalpop']."</td></tr>";
    $rank++;
  }
}
```

And output of the codes is :

```
Greatest Alliance
   Alliance    player       Ø   points
 1. multii       3          4     11
 2. multii       3          2      6
 3. multii       3          2      6
 4. myallianc    2          5      5
 5. myallianc    2          1      2
```

but this is not correct !!! . in real travian for each alliance is just one row in statics so the output of my code is wrong . the correct output for each alliance must be like :

```
Greatest Alliance
   Alliance    player       Ø   points
 1. multii       3          8    23
 2. myallianc    2          6    7
```

For every alliance must be only one row

Comment: Are you sure that the second row is `2. myallianc    3          6    7` not `2. myallianc    2          6    7`?

Comment: You know the `groupy by` statement?

Comment: @Mahmoud Gamal : sry I edit my post , it must be 2 players . tnx

Comment: @MahmoudGamal Sry im not pro and idont know RDBMS :(( sry

Comment: @Benjaminfox Sorry I meant what type of databases you are working with. From the error you posted it is MySQL.

Comment: @Mahmoud Gamal : no im sry , im noob . im using wampserver in local , phpmyadmin . again sry if i answer wrong :(( i know this problem will not be fix because im not pro and noob :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should be written this way:

```
SELECT 
  u.id userid, 
  u.username username, 
  u.alliance allyid, 
  SUM(v.pop )   AS totalpop, 
  SUM(a.Aap ) AS totalpoint,
  COUNT(ua.alliance ) AS totalusers
FROM users u
INNER JOIN vdata    v ON v.owner     = u.userid
INNER JOIN alidata  a ON a.id        = u.allyid
INNER JOIN users   ua ON ua.alliance = u.allyid
WHERE users.alliance > 0
GROUP BY u.id,
         u.username, 
         u.alliance 
ORDER BY u.totalpoint DESC, 
         u.allyid ASC ;
```

**What I have done in this query:**

I `JOIN`ed the tables `users`, `vdata`, `alidata` and `users` again instead of these correlated subqueries that you used in your question. **Note that:** I joined the table `users` one more times to get those users that has `alliance = u.allyid` but with a different alias. Then `GROUP BY`, with aggregate functions in the same query.

You might also need to use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` in case you want to include those unmtached data, i.e those users that has no entries in the others tables for example.

---

### Update 1

To test the query against MySQL directly, and since you are using WAMP. Like in the following steps:

- **Ensure that the WAMP server is running:**

[image]

- **From the task par open the phpMyAdmin:**

[image]

- **Select your database that you're working with:**

[image]

- **Navigate to SQL Tab:**

[image]

- **Paste your query in the window:**

[image]

- **Then press the button Go.**

---

### Update 1

Try this instead:

```
SELECT 
  u.id               AS userid, 
  u.username         AS username, 
  u.alliance         AS allyid, 
  SUM(v.pop)         AS totalpop, 
  SUM(a.Aap)         AS totalpoint,
  COUNT(ua.alliance) AS totalusers
FROM s1_users u
LEFT JOIN s1_vdata    v ON v.owner     = u.id
LEFT JOIN s1_alidata  a ON a.id        = u.alliance
LEFT JOIN s1_users   ua ON ua.alliance = u.alliance
WHERE u.alliance > 0 
GROUP BY u.id, 
         u.username, 
         u.alliance;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7aacd/4)

This will give you:

```
| USERID |    USERNAME | ALLYID | TOTALPOP | TOTALPOINT | TOTALUSERS |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|      4 | Multihunter |      1 |       18 |          0 |          3 |
|      5 |     tester1 |      1 |       33 |          0 |          3 |
|      6 |     tester2 |      1 |       18 |          0 |          3 |
```

**Note that:** I couldn't find a column `allyid` in the `s1_users` table, so I joined the table `s1_users` with `s1_alidata` with the column `alliance` and `s1_users` with itself with the same field `alliance`. Not sure if this is right or not.

---

But there is a big problem in your tables' design. Your tables are [***normalized***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

For instance, it seems that the fields `Tribe`, `Access`, `Gold` and `Silver` are related attributes for each user, so you can move them to a new table something like:

**`UsersFooProperties`:**

- `PropertyId`,
- `UserId` a foreign key to the users table,
- `Tribe`,
- `Access`,
- `Gold`,
- `Silver`,
- Composite key(`ProertyId`, userid`).

The same for the fields `B1`, `B2`, `B3` and `B4`, move them to a new table:

**`UsersBs`:**

- `UserId`,
- `B1`,
- `B2`,
- `B3`.

However, if these `B`s are more than three and there are other properties for this `B` proeprty, you can create a new table `Bs`:

**`Bes`**:

- BID,
- other properties here ...

Then:

**`UsersBs`:**

- `UserId`,
- `BID`,
- Composite key(`Userid`, `BID`).

Another big issue is with those 38 fields: `friend1`, ... , `friend19`, `friend1wait`, ..., `friend19wait`.

You have to have a separate table for those friends like this:

**`UsersFriends:**

- `UserId` a foreign key to the users table,
- `FriendID`,
- `WaitOrNot` a flag 0 or 1.

There for you have only one column friend, in this column you can insert all the friends of these 38 columns like this:

```
UserId FriendId WaitOrNot
  1       1         0
  1       2         1
  1       3         0
  ...
  ...
  1       19        1
```

Also try to avoid storing mutiple values as a comma separated string value, like what you did in the column `FQUEST`. Make a new table for it like this:

**`UsersFQUEST`:**

- `UserID`,
- `FQUESTId`.

This was just an example of how you can redesign one of your table `users` these are just a sample of bad things you have in this table, you have other columns than these that I mentioned. You have also to do the same things for other tables.

For more information, see these:

- [**Join (SQL)<sup>From Wikipedia</sup>**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29).
- [**Visual Representation of SQL Joins**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins).
- [**Another Visual Explanation of SQL Joins**](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).
- [**SQL Queries for Mere Mortals(R): A Hands-On Guide to Data Manipulation in SQL**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201433362), a great book for SQL Basics.
- [**A Simple Guide to Five Normal Forms in Relational Database Theory**](http://www.bkent.net/Doc/simple5.htm).

Comment: i put your code exactly but ouput will send error :
Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in C:\wamp\www\Templates\Ranking\alliance.tpl on line 40

Comment: @Benjaminfox **Note that:** I omit all those prefixes `" . TB_PREFIX . "` that you had in your query, you should add them. But what is the error you got, please try to post it. Also try to test the query directly with the RDBMS you are using before trying it within php and ensure it works properly.

Comment: code in line 40 is :
$sql = $ranking->procAllianceRanking();$query = mysql_num_rows($sql);

@test the query directly with the RDBMS : im not pro and i dont know what is RDBMS :(

i test with prefix and the same error :((

im not Lazy but can you a favor and give me the final code cus i cant undrestand this codes, tnx

Comment: @Benjaminfox Sorry for confusion, Can you please test this query directly in the my phpMyadmin directly?

Comment: oh men :( im realy realy realy sry . but if you favor me and explain with picture ? i think its only way to im get undrestand :(( . and its ok if you cant do that .

Comment: @Benjaminfox OK, see my edit. Try it and let me now what you got.

Comment: Wonderfully laid out answer, with pictures!

Comment: @MahmoudGamal : i dont know how to tanx you :X  its say : #1146 - Table 't4_farsi.users' doesn't exist       my tables is : http://img.ir/PQq.png  this is image of my tables but when i get to table users and add querry then press go the error will gone and nothing show , this mean its ok ?

Comment: @Benjaminfox - It is `s1_users` not `users`.

Comment: yes , when i set query in users there is no error come . ( sry for bad english ) there is no error . this mean the code is ok ?

Comment: @Benjaminfox - Do you got the results you are looking for?

Comment: @Benjaminfox - Sorry for that. Can you please edit your question and show me some sample data of these three tables `vdata`, `alidata` and `users` it will be very helpful, and if possible try to setup a demo [in this site](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/) Thanks. Sorry I have to go now and I will be back couple of hours later.

Comment: tnx. i dont know how to use that site . sir this problem is very important to me and i can u use my pc with team viewer ? i will access u to my pc . PLZ ! tnx for everything

Comment: @Benjaminfox Can you add them to your question instead, I just want some sample data of these three tables involved, you can put them in your question. Or, if you couldn't try to put them in a file and upload it to any upload sites dropbox or any other site. I will help you certainly, so please this will be very helpful, and sorry for my late.

Comment: tnx . this is export of my db : http://www.4shared.com/zip/fewBClvf/db_online.html

Comment: @Benjaminfox OK, but give me couple of minutes and I will let you know.

Comment: TNX i will be back in 2 hours ,

Comment: @Benjaminfox - Sorry for late, See my update. What do you think?

Comment: @MahmoudGamal : Tnx the code is ok . script will create database  automatic and i  didnt do that like  friendswait . BUT ! still my problem did not solved because:
the output is still : 

  1. multii 3 22 66
  2. multii 3 19 57
  3. multii 3 6 18

i think problem is output code : the code is in my question

Comment: @Benjaminfox But it is working fine [**as you can see in this demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7aacd/4), isn't this right?

Comment: yes its ok , as i say i thing this this for wrong output code in demo i cant find output code , and is guess 100% the problem is output code . the code in demo and your post is ok and right

Comment: oh the code is wrong !!! because the allyid ( alliance name or code ) is 3 for each user , it must show only one

Comment: @Benjaminfox As I said in my answer, I couldn't find any allyid in the users table. Is this right? So I assumed it is `alliance`.

Comment: yes idont know how this is work with allyid . but tnx alot for helping me sir. can u do that for each alliance code ( 0 , 1 , ....) show only one row ?

Comment: @Benjaminfox - If this is not what you are looking for, or anything goes wrong don't hesitate to ask again and again. For your last comment, what do you mean by *`do that for each alliance`*? If you mean get the result for alliance 0 then add a `WHERE users.alliance = 0` to do this for multiple values: `WHERE users.alliance IN (0, 1, 2, ...)`

Comment: i mean to show all users with ALLYID 1 , show only ALLIANCE with ALLYID 1 in one row then in next row SHow alliance with allyid 2 in one row , ....

Comment: i fix my problem but : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7aacd/23 the number of players is wrong !! it will power number . the real player number is = 3 , but it shows 9

Comment: @Benjaminfox Sorry I can't understand, in your data there is only one alliance = 0. And if you want the output that you are looking for one alliance per row, put it in the `GROUP BY` [**like in this**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7aacd/28). Can you please edit your question and show me the exact output you are trying to get for the sample data in this demo.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7491b/1 : in this i have 3 players with allyid 1 and 2 players with allyid 2 , so : in line 1 of output see TOTALUSERS with value = 9 . but i only have 3 users . it must show TOTALUSERS = 3 not 9

Comment: @Benjaminfox - OK, Sorry I missed that. What about [**this updated fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7491b/4). Just use `COUNT(DISTINCT ua.id)` instead.

Comment: I LOOOOOOVEEEEEE YOOOOOUUUUUU SIIIIIR :D work Fine :X ( im not gay :D) tnx alot alot alot alot alot . god give you anything you want :X tnx 4 everything

Comment: @Benjaminfox - You're welcome anytime. Glad I could help :) Feel free to ask again if anything goes wrong.